# New (x, y) position after rotating around z-axis

Tags: geometry

I have line with end position (x1, y1) that I know. How can I calculate new position (x2, y2) after I rotate that line around it's z-axis by 40 degrees?

I draw the situation in the image below to help clarify.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acmoc.png)

Comment: Have you tried using polar coordinates?

Comment: @R.Burton Hi, yes I tried them in many forms, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you provide more detail?

Comment: @R.Burton I can try. For example I tried r = sqrt(pow(x1, 2) + pow(y1, 2)) -> x2 = r * cos(φ), y2 = r*sin(φ), but that's not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Basic Algebra/Trigonometry**

To convert from Cartesian to polar coordinates, use the identity...

$$(r,\theta)=\text{CtoP}(x,y)=\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2},\text{atan2}(y,x)\right)$$

...where $\text{atan2}$ is the [two-argument arctangent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

To convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates, use the identity...

$$(x,y)=\text{PtoC}(r,\theta)=(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta})$$

...where $r$ is the distance from the origin $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$, and $\theta$ is the angle formed by the line passing through $(0,0,)$ and $(x,y)$ and the $x$ axis.

In the context of your problem, $(x_2,y_2)=\text{PtoC}(\text{CtoP}(x_1,y,1)+(0,40^\circ))$.

Explicitly:

$$(x_2,y_2)=\left(\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}\cos(\text{atan2}(y_1,x_1)+40^\circ),\sqrt{{x_1}^2+{y_1}^2}\sin(\text{atan2}(y_1,x_1)+40^\circ)\right)$$

**Using Linear Algebra**

The [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) for a rotation of $\theta$ in the Cartesian plane is given by...

$$\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}$$

Using matrix-vector multiplication...

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_2\\y_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\y_1\end{bmatrix}$$

Explicitly:

$$(x_2,y_2) = (x_1\cos(40^\circ)-y_1\sin(40^\circ),x_1\sin(40^\circ)+y_1\cos(40^\circ))$$